# Dynamic table pagination based on available space

Tags: reactjs, html-table, pagination, frontend, responsive

I have a table and I filled it with REST API with KeySet-based pagination. I have used pagination contains 5 buttons for representative of pages.

I want to use all the available space to display the maximum number of rows in the table, but at the same time, making the page smaller and larger does not lead to scrolling inside the table. So, I do not mean usual responsive.

I tried a solution that caused some sequential problems. I think it would be better to go back and look for a better idea from the beginning. Do you have any solutions based on your experience?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but I do not understand your problem, but maybe this could help you.
There is a WEB API called "Intersection Observer API". With this observer, you can reach out to the elements in the view of your device. Maybe this can help you, bro.

Comment: Thank you Esmaeil. I didn't know about "Intersection Observer API" before. Anyway, It can't help in this case.

`Implemented`:
To implement a dynamic table, I only considered the available space in the initial rendering and calculated the number of rows that can be displayed on the screen.

`Improvement point`:
After the initial rendering, I want to increase or decrease the browser height without resulting in free space or scrolling in the table.